# jQuery .submit() woes with IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit a delete link click via a http post to my asp.net mvc controller. While my code below works for chrome it does not work in IE8. Any pointer will be very useful.

Setup:

- Browser: IE8
- jQuery: 1.4.1
- MVC: 2.0

The delete link is:-

```
<a title="Delete contact" href="/Contacts/Delete/<%= Model.Contact.Id %>" class="delete" rel="Are you sure you want to delete <%= Html.Encode(Model.Contact.Name) %>?">Delete</a>
```

and the jQuery handler for the click of delete is

```
$("a.delete").click(function() {
if (confirm($(this).attr("rel"))) {
    var form = "<form method='POST' action='" + $(this).attr("href") + '" style='display:none;'></form>";
        $(form).submit();
    }
    return false; });
```

Comment: "It does not work" questions are difficult. How does it not work? What errors do you get? What does it do in IE8? Do you have any idea which of those lines IE breaks on, if it is showing you a script error.

Comment: Your quotes are mixed up. You say it works in chrome, so maybe a copy/paste error? Also jQuery 1.4 allows you to break up element creation with attributes like this - `$("<form />", { "method" : "post", action: "...", style: ".." })`. It is a much cleaner way compared to the quote-soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to append the form to body before you can submit it? Not sure how it works in Chrome without that, but try doing something like this-

```
$('<form/>', {
    action: "...",
    method: "...",
    style: "...",
})
.appendTo("body")
.submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

IE does not submit disabled elements in a form, so maybe it's the same with empty forms.

It's not exactly a solution, but I would do that without creating a form. You can just use *$.ajax* or *$.post* and build the required URL with *Url.Action(...)*, then call *document.reload()*.

Comment: This is how I would do it. Easier to debug and manage with `$.post`

Comment: *"IE does not submit disabled elements in a form..."* No browser submits disabled elements in a form -- at least, not if they want to follow the specification, which says not to: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm (that's a link to the HTML5 spec, but this is old, old behavior)